# Position of a point with respect to two reference frames

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, vectors

I working on a project where doing some image processing detect objects using Kinect camera and then move it to a desired location with a help of robotic arm. In this project the sensor gives pixel coordinates (X, Y, Z ) but since I am not sure where is the origin of the camera. I am defining my own reference frame with four points on the image captured. I believe by doing so will help me move the object to desired location with ease using a manipulator.
[image]

If I have another point Q(x, y, z) in pixel coordinates. How do I find the point Q(x, y, and z) with respect to the coordinate system that I have defined using the four points? I know it is related to vectors. I did some readings and came across a lot of articles on translations, rotation and scaling. I am not sure how to approach the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my idea:

step $1$: get the matrix of your frame of four points:
$$M=[\frac{\vec{P_0P_1}}{|\vec{P_0P_1}|}\quad\frac{\vec{P_0P_2}}{|\vec{P_0P_2}|}\quad\frac{\vec{P_0P_3}}{|\vec{P_0P_3}|}]$$
here we normalise the three vectors to make sure that $\det M=1$. In fact $M$ is the transformation matrix of your frame in the inertial coordinate frame.

step $2$: get the coordinate of the point $Q$ with respect of your frame (we note it $Q$): denote that the coordinate of the point $Q$ with respect of the inertial coordinate frame is $Q_0$, then we have this equation:
$$Q_0=MQ+P_0$$
where $Q_0$ is what you have in your project. then
$$Q=M^{-1}(Q_0-P_0)$$
this is what you want.

you can consult this book for more theoretical details: "A Mathematical Introduction to Robotic Manipulation" by Richard M. Murray, Zexiang Li and S. Shankar Sastry.

Comment: Most likely the reference frames are connected by an affine transformation, not by a linear transformation.

Comment: yes, you are right, I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provide is insufficient to say anything about the location of $Q$. You need (at least) the location of $P_0. P_1, P_2, P_3$ in the same coordinate system as you have the location of $Q$ in. Then you need an affine transformation $T: x\mapsto Ax + b$ wich maps
$$P_0 \mapsto (0,0,0), P_1 \mapsto (1,0,0), P_2 \mapsto (0,1,0), P_3 \mapsto (0,0,1)$$
You answer is then given by $q_P = Tq$. To find $T$, you see that the inverse of $T$ is given by
$$T^{-1}x = \begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\P_1-P_0&P_2-P_0&P_3-P_0\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}x + P_0$$
In other words, assuming $P_i$ are the coordinates of the points seen as a column vector in the same reference frame as the coordinates of $Q$, you have
$$q_P = \begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\P_1-P_0&P_2-P_0&P_3-P_0\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}^{-1} (Q-P_0)$$